# Multisite solution favicon.ico problem in nginx

Tags: php, regex, dns, nginx, url-rewriting

```
if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.([a-zA-Z1-9-_]+).([a-zA-Z]+)\/favicon.ico(/?)+$"){
set $domainp1 $2;
set $domainp2 $3;
rewrite ^/favicon.ico(/?)+$ /uploads/$domainp1.$domainp2/favicon.ico last;
break;
}
```

Hello Developers.

I need to configure my favicon.ico for multiple sites. The above code has some problems and does not work. What should be done to achieve my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($host ~* "^([a-zA-Z1-9\-_]+\.|)([a-zA-Z1-9\-_]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$"){

set $domainp1 $2;
set $domainp2 $3;
rewrite ^/favicon.ico(/?)+$ /uploads/$domainp1.$domainp2/favicon.ico last;
}
```

this code works now. is there any other solution?